# React Native TextInput won't focus after showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to focus the TextInput after being hidden. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Need help!

Here's my code:

```
React.Component {
  state = {
    isEditing: false
  }

  onEdit() {
    this.setState({isEditing: true});
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {isEditing ? (
        <TextInput ref={(input) => this.textInput = input} value="Hello, World!"/>
        ) : (
        <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onEdit.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Edit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is an asynchronous call, you have to wait for it to complete. do:

```js
onEdit() {
    this.setState({isEditing: true}, () => {
        this.textInput.focus();
    });
}
```

But in your case, `textInput` may not ready yet even after `setState` complete. You take `ref` callback from `textInput`, and that might be slower than your `setState` callback. In your case every time `<TextInput />` shows, it needs to be focused, suggest to set focus in place

```js
<TextInput ref={(input) => {
    input.focus();
    this.textInput = input;
} value="Hello, World!"/>
```

Or an ugly `setTimeout` inside `setState` callback would do the trick.

Comment: it works! thanks a lot. I didn't know that there's a callback in setting a state :)

Answer (score 0):

You also have a "typo" on conditional:
`{isEditing ? ( ... )}`

should be: `{this.state.isEditing ? ( ... )}`

Comment: i forgot to add 

`const {isEditing} = this.state;`